# What does the "o" stand for in 9 o'clock?

Tags: word-meaning, pronunciation, abbreviations

Why do we use "o" in  telling the time, e.g. 9 o'clock?

I looked it up in the dictionary but it did not say anything about the letter.

> ### [o'clock](https://www.lexico.com/definition/o%27clock)
>
> **adverb**
> Used to specify the hour when telling the time.
>
> - ‘the gates will open at eight o'clock’

What does the "o" stand for?

Comment: In this case, the ***o'*** has a historical derivation, but speakers don't think of it as short for anything anymore.  You can't replace it with *of the*.  So this is a matter of etymology;  it's not like "lots o' luck" where ***o'*** represents a reduced colloquial form of *of*.  You'll have to learn *o'clock* as a single word.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This website](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=o%27clock&searchmode=term) explains it quite nicely:

> **o'clock** (*adj.*) 
>   c.1720, abbreviation of ***of the clock*** (1640s), from Middle English *of the clokke* (late 14c.).

The usage of *o'* as a shortened way to say *of* is not uncommon (this is called an [*apocopic*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/apocopic) form, when the last syllable or consonant is left unpronounced). Many o' these are relatively rare in written form, but you might see them when an author was trying to capture colloquial elocution in a quote:

- *"All I needed was the queen o' hearts for a straight flush!"*
- *"Yer startin' your new job tomorrah, Jim? Well, best o' luck to ya!"*

For some reason, *o'clock* is one exception where the *o'* became not only common, but formal.

---

<sub>"[colloquial](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/colloquial) [elocution](https://www.wordnik.com/words/elocution)" is a fancy way of saying "how people say words informally"</sub>

Comment: or "how folk really talk"

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer here correctly explains that the "o'" contraction is short for "of the", but it does not explain how it came to be in the first place.

Prior to the introduction of clocks, there were other indicators of time, like celestial bodies. Even when clocks were introduced, very few people had them, and common people still used other means to tell the time. (It should be noted that the concept of counting time in hours precedes clocks). It was customary to refer to e.g. the fourth hour of the day based on the time elapsed since sunrise.

However, with the introduction of clocks, it became necessary to distinguish time told from one means to the time told by a clock, as they would not always correspond. (The sun comes up earlier in summer and later in winter). Therefore, to make the distinction that time referred to was being told by a clock, one would say "of the clock".

Answer (score -1):

8 o' clock is correctly said as 8 on clock

Comment: Can you say where that is the case? It does not correspond to what I hear in the UK.